# Vectorized indexing for a dictionary

Tags: julia

I would like to find a succinct syntax in Julia for indexing a dictionary in a vectorized manner. In R, I would do the following:

```
dict <- c("a" = 1, "b" = 2)
keys <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a")
dict[keys]
```

In Julia, if I have a `dict` and `keys` like this,

```
dict = Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2)
keys = [:a, :a, :b, :b, :a]
```

then I can achieve the desired result using a list comprehension:

```
julia> [dict[key] for key in keys]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 2
 1
```

Is there a more succinct vectorized syntax, similar to the R syntax?

Answer (score 13):

```
getindex.(Ref(dict), keys)
```

You can wrap it in `Ref` so you don't need to `[]` it.

Comment: Sorry for the naïve question, but why does this work?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little macro (using the brilliant MacroTools package):

```
using MacroTools
macro vget(ex)
    @capture(ex, dict_.[idxvec_])
    :(map(i->$dict[i], $idxvec)) |> esc
end
```

Then you can:

```
d = Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2)
ks = [:a, :a, :b, :b, :a]

@vget d.[ks]
```

I probably wouldn't want to use that in production code, something like your list comprehension, or a simple map: `map(i->d[i], ks)`, is more readable/explicit/standard, but it *is* fun :D

Comment: wonder if compiling an extra anonymous function is that something we should avoid

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to be frequently using the dictionary as a lookup table, then it might be worth creating a closure to use as a lookup function:

```
make_lookup(dict) = key -> dict[key]    

dict = Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2)

lookup = make_lookup(dict)
```

Then you can use `lookup` in a vectorized fashion:

```
julia> keys = [:a, :a, :b, :b, :a];

julia> lookup.(keys)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 2
 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the vectorized version of `getindex`:

```
julia> getindex.([dict], keys)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 2
 1
```

Note that `dict` is wrapped in an array so that `getindex` does not attempt to broadcast over the elements of the dictionary:

```
julia> getindex.(dict, keys)
ERROR: ArgumentError: broadcasting over dictionaries and `NamedTuple`s is reserved
Stacktrace:
 [1] broadcastable(::Dict{Symbol,Int64}) at ./broadcast.jl:615
 [2] broadcasted(::Function, ::Dict{Symbol,Int64}, ::Array{Symbol,1}) at ./broadcast.jl:1164
 [3] top-level scope at none:0
```

Comment: I think it's preferable to use `getindex.((dict,), keys)` or `getindex.(Ref(dict), keys)`, since `[dict]` will allocate an array.