# Create array of values based on dictionary and array of keys

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia, so I'm sorry if this is a basic question.

Say we have a dictionary, and a vector of keys:

```
X = [2, 1, 1, 3]
d = Dict( 1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "C")
```

I want to create a new array which contains values instead of keys (according to the dictionary), so the end result would be something like

```
Y = ["B", "A", "A", "C"]
```

I suppose I could iterate over the vector elements, look it up in the dictionary and return the corresponding value, but this seems awfully inefficient to me.
Something like

```
Y = Array{String}(undef, length(X))
for i in 1:length(X)
    Y[i] = d[X[i]]
end
```

EDIT: Also, my proposed solution doesn't work if `X` contains `missing` values.

So my question is if there is some more efficient way of doing this (I'm doing it with a much larger array and dictionary), or is this an appropriate way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vectorized indexing for a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034758/vectorized-indexing-for-a-dictionary)

Comment: Your own suggestion is super-efficient, and probably the fastest possible solution. Loops in Julia are extremely fast, and are normally the optimal solution. Note just that instead of length-1 strings you can use `Char`s, like `'A'`, which are faster.

Comment: @DNF thanks! I didn't know about `Char`s. I guess my only remaining question is related to my edit: can this be adapted to work when `X` has `missing` values? I guet `KeyError: key missing not found` if I implement this.

Comment: I edited my answer below for this.

Comment: What should it do if X has a missing?  Skip the missing value in X?  There's a function `skipmissing` which will do that...

Comment: There are several good solutions, some are terse, and some are verbose, but the important take-away here is that loops are fast, and you do not necessarily need to go looking for canned 'built-in' solutions. Your own loopy code will be fast. This takes some time to learn for Matlabbers, Pythonistas and R-users ;)

Comment: @DNF Yeah, coming from R and Python this is mindblowing. Thank you all for the responses and general advice!

Comment: @CPhil the problem with that is that the resulting vector doesn't preserve the missing entries; see my comment to Nils' answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efficiency can mean different things in different contexts, but I would probably do:

```
Y = [d[i] for i in X]
```

If `X` contains `missing` values, you could use `skipmissing(X)` in the comprehension.

Comment: That's brilliant! Can it be adapted to handle `missing` values in `X`? (I edited the question).

Comment: `skipmissing(X)` works but then `Y` is not of the same length as `X`. However, I found out that adding a key-value pair for `missing` in the dictionary allows me to use your proposed solution and keep the missing values in `Y`:
`d = Dict{Union{Integer, Missing}, Union{String, Missing}}( 1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "C", missing => missing)`

Comment: As far as I can tell, `[d[i] for i in skipmissing(X)]` works for the general case, without needing any extra keyval pair in the dict. Or, do you actually need them to be of equal lenght?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I need to preserve entries with missing values (so yes, same length).

Answer (score 5):

You can use an array comprehension to do this pretty tersely:

```
julia> [d[x] for x in X]
4-element Array{String,1}:
 "B"
 "A"
 "A"
 "C"
```

In the future it may be possible to write `d.[X]` to express this even more concisely, but as of Julia 1.3, that is not yet allowed.

As per the edit to the question, let's suppose there is a `missing` value somewhere in `X`:

```
julia> X = [2, 1, missing, 1, 3]
5-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 2
 1
  missing
 1
 3
```

If you want to map `missing` to `missing` or some other value like the string `"?"` you can do that explicitly like this:

```
julia> [ismissing(x) ? missing : d[x] for x in X]
5-element Array{Union{Missing, String},1}:
 "B"
 "A"
 missing
 "A"
 "C"

julia> [ismissing(x) ? "?" : d[x] for x in X]
5-element Array{String,1}:
 "B"
 "A"
 "?"
 "A"
 "C"
```

If you're going to do that a lot, it might be easier to put `missing` in the dictionary like this:

```
julia> d = Dict(missing => "?", 1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "C")
Dict{Union{Missing, Int64},String} with 4 entries:
  2       => "B"
  missing => "?"
  3       => "C"
  1       => "A"

julia> [d[x] for x in X]
5-element Array{String,1}:
 "B"
 "A"
 "?"
 "A"
 "C"
```

If you want to simply skip over missing values, you can use `skipmissing(X)` instead of `X`:

```
julia> [d[x] for x in skipmissing(X)]
4-element Array{String,1}:
 "B"
 "A"
 "A"
 "C"
```

There's generally not a single correct way to handle missing values, which is why you need to explicitly code how to handle missing data.

Comment: What if `X` contains `missing`?  (See the comments above)